# How to secure upload file?

Tags: php, laravel, security, xss

i want to ask about uploading files (images) to Laravel storage (local).

```
//validation rules for image - image|mimes:jpeg,png|max:2048
$img = $request->file('image');
$img->storeAs('somepath', 'filename');
```

Is is safely?
I mean what if image will contains some EXIF keys with injection code in it?
Or smth else.

Comment: Add SSL Certificate; and use this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/196679/173911

Answer (score 0):

you could use imagick to resave the file 
createFromFile and then saveToFile

Comment: Unless ImageMagick has a vulnerability.